# Como pegar uma div de outra página html com js puro?

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu quero carregar uma lista de uma `div`, de uma página para outra (ambas no meu servidor). Eu sei que para isso existe a função [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) `$('#content').load('paginaexemplo.htm' '#lista')`, mas eu gostaria de saber como eu faço isso com [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) puro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma com XMLHttpRequest:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url_ = "pagina.php"; // página de onde virá a div
http.open("GET", url_, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(http.readyState == 4){
      var html = http.responseText;
      // converte o retorno em elementos HTML
      html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      document.getElementById('id_da_div_que_irá_receber').innerHTML = html.getElementById('id_da_div_que_de_onde_virá').innerHTML.trim();
   }
}
http.send(null);
```

Comment: Bom dia,esse código funcionou muito bem no firefox e até no explorer,mas no CHROME ele não executa de forma alguma.Eu já procurei saber o que poderia ser mas não encontrei solucão,tem alguma dica do que pode ser o problema?

Comment: Agora descobri o problema,por questões de segurança o chrome exige que a página esteja com algum protocolo,no caso,eu hospedei minhas páginas num host para teste e com protocolo https,e funcionou,de qualquer forma vlw

Comment: Ah sim, o Chrome bloqueia se não for HTTP...

Comment: Olá Luan! Quando estiver online, favor dá um toque. Queria tirar uma dúvida. Valeu!

Comment: Pois não sam,onde quer tirar sua dúvida?

Comment: Obg Luan, já resolvi já. Valeu!